# Hello.c Error on Linux Terminal (C Language)

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I input into the terminal:

```
[File: hello/hello.c]
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     printf("Hello World\n");
     return (0);
}
```

The terminal kicked back two errors:

```
     hello.c:1:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token
     [File: hello/hello.c]
     ^
     hello.c:2:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
     compilation terminated.
```

I would like some clarification of what I did wrong here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try again with /*[File: hello/hello.c]*/, stdio.h should have found though

Comment: No! You must provide the source that you're following. I found this in "Practical C Programming (1997)" Is it that? Otherwise typo questions are strictly off-topic on Stack Overflow if they're unlikely to help *other* readers.

Answer (score 1):

`[File: hello/hello.c]` should **not** be placed at top-level.
Just remove or comment it out.